# How to define contrast coefficient matrix?

Tags: matrix, anova, contrast

I have this data

```
y x1 x2 pre
1  16  1  1  14
2  15  1  1  13
3  14  1  2  14
4  13  1  2  13
5  12  2  1  12
6  11  2  1  12
7  11  2  2  13
8  13  2  2  13
9  10  3  1  10
10 11  3  1  11
11 11  3  2  11
12  9  3  2  10
```

And I fitted the following model

```
lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x1*x2)
```

My design matrix is

```
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
 [1,]    1   14    1    0    1    1    0
 [2,]    1   13    1    0    1    1    0
 [3,]    1   14    1    0    0    0    0
 [4,]    1   13    1    0    0    0    0
 [5,]    1   12    0    1    1    0    1
 [6,]    1   12    0    1    1    0    1
 [7,]    1   13    0    1    0    0    0
 [8,]    1   13    0    1    0    0    0
 [9,]    1   10    0    0    1    0    0
[10,]    1   11    0    0    1    0    0
[11,]    1   11    0    0    0    0    0
[12,]    1   10    0    0    0    0    0
```

I'm trying to use this design to reproduce the following table:

```
Source DF Squares Mean Square F Value Pr > F
Model 6 44.79166667 7.46527778 12.98 0.0064
Error 5 2.87500000 0.57500000
Corrected Total 11 47.66666667

Source DF Type III SS Mean Square F Value Pr > F
pre 1 3.12500000 3.12500000 5.43 0.0671
x1 2 4.58064516 2.29032258 3.98 0.0923
x2 1 3.01785714 3.01785714 5.25 0.0706
x1*x2 2 1.25000000 0.62500000 1.09 0.4055
```

The first part is fine

```
XtX <- t(x) %*% x
XtXinv <- solve(XtX)
betahat <- XtXinv %*% t(x) %*% y

H <- x %*% XtXinv %*% t(x) 
IH <- (diag(1,12) - H)
yhat <- H %*% y 
e <- IH %*% y
ybar <- mean(y)

MSS <- t(betahat) %*% t(x) %*% y - length(y)*(ybar^2) 
ESS <- t(e) %*% e 
TSS <- MSS + ESS 

dfM <- sum(diag(H)) - 1 
dfE <- sum(diag(IH)) 
dfT <- dfM + dfE 

MSM <- MSS/dfM 
MSE <- ESS/dfE 

Ftest <- MSM / MSE
pr <- 1 - pf(Ftest, dfM, dfE)
```

The contrast coefficient matrix for 'pre' seems correct.

```
L <- matrix(c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0), 1, 7, byrow=T)
Lb <- L %*% betahat 
LXtXinvLt <- round(L %*% XtXinv %*% t(L), digits=4) 
SSpre <- t(Lb) %*% solve(LXtXinvLt) %*% (Lb) 
MSpre <- SSpre / 1 
Fpre <- MSpre / MSE 
PRpre <- 1 - pf(Fpre, 1, 12-7)
```

But I can't understand how to define the contrast coefficient matrix for x1, x2, and x1*x2. What's the problem with the rest of my code? Below an example for how I think I should calculate for x1

```
L <- matrix(c(0,0,1,1,0,0,0), 1, 7, byrow=T)
Lb <- L %*% betahat 
LXtXinvLt <- round(L %*% XtXinv %*% t(L), digits=4) 
SSX1 <- t(Lb) %*% solve(LXtXinvLt) %*% (Lb) 
MSX1 <- SSX1 / 1 
FX1 <- MSX1 / MSE 
PRX1 <- 1 - pf(FX1, 1, 12-7)
```

Thanks!